# MIPS How do I convert a j instruction to machine code?

Tags: mips

I need to convert this jump to binary and I can't figure out how to get the immediate value. I tried doing it by taking the base address of the Loop which was assumed to be 40000 then divide it by 4 (40000 / 4 = 10000) but I don't know if this is correct (That was just how they did it in an example in my book).

```
    Loop: slt $t0,$s0,$s1
          beq $t0,1,Exit
          sub $s0,$s0,$s1;
          j Loop;
    Exit:
```

Answer (score 1):

Bits 25..0 of the `j` instruction become bits 27..2 of the `PC` and bits 1..0 become 00 (this is the divide by 4 business). This works because addresses are always 4-byte aligned.

So if `Loop` is at address 40,000 then the bottom 26 bits of the instruction are 00 0000 0000 0010 0111 0001 0000 (10,000) and the other 6 bits are the `j` opcode (0000 10).

When the instruction executes the value (10,000 in your case) is extracted and shifted left 2 bits (which is multiplying by 4). Then this value replaces the bottom 28 bits of the PC -- the top 4 bits (0000 in your case) remain unchanged.  The next instruction your program executes will be at address 40,000.